# Script does not contain errors but game is not getting over

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float jumpPower = 100f;
    Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    bool isRoad = false;
    bool isGameOver = false;
    public float xPos = -17.4f;

    void Start()
    {
       myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }

    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
       if (isGameOver) return;
       

       
       
       if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && isRoad )
       {
           myRigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up *myRigidbody.gravityScale*myRigidbody.mass* jumpPower * Time.deltaTime  );
       } 
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if(other.collider.tag == "Road") 
        {
            isRoad = true;

        }

        if(other.collider.tag == "Obstacles") 
        {
            GameOver();

        }
    
         
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if(other.collider.tag == "Road") 
        {
            isRoad = false;

        }
        
    }

    private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if(other.collider.tag == "Road") 
        {
            isRoad = true;

        }
    }

    public void GameOver()
    {
        myRigidbody.gravityScale = 0f;
        isGameOver = true;
        FindObjectOfType<ChallengeScroller>().GameOver();
        FindObjectOfType<Scroll>().xVel =0f;
        FindObjectOfType<ScrollClouds>().xVel =0f;
    }
}
```

1. This is the normal text

please tell me what should I add extra codes are am I doing any errors, although player and obstacles are not getting collide with each other, instead obstacles are pushing the player backside. here I have used to call the Gameover function

`if(other.collider.tag == "Obstacles")
{
GameOver();

```
    }`
```

Answer (score 2):

For collision to work in Unity, you need to have Rigid Body on both Game Objects, and "Trigger" activated on one of the colliders. In case of 2D Collision, you need only one object with a RigidBody2D, and both with 2D Colliders.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html